# How do I edit a JPEG's EXIF data with Gimp?

Tags: gimp, jpeg, exif, exiftool

I would like to edit a JPG EXIF data in Gimp. Perhaps I need a plugin or something, but I don't know how to search for and download the plugin. Plus, when Gimp opens a JPG it converts it to XCF format. Hopefully when I export it again the EXIF data will still be there. Thanks.

Comment: See also [here](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1512/are-there-gimp-plugins-that-allow-one-to-view-and-edit-exif-data).

Comment: I can't seem to open the link.

Comment: Odd. The link is [http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1512/are-there-gimp-plugins-that-allow-one-to-view-and-edit-exif-data](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1512/are-there-gimp-plugins-that-allow-one-to-view-and-edit-exif-data)

Comment: Thanks. Now it's working. Yes I had found that page, but it is geared towards Linux users and I'm on Windows 7. And you have to untar and unzip and compile and install it form scratch. I was wondering if you could install a plugin in Gimp via a URL, just like in the Eclipse IDE? Thanks.

Comment: I see. At the moment I'm using an external tool ([IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/)). There is a lot of free tools for Windows, e.g. [GeoSetter](http://www.geosetter.de/en), [ExifTool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/), etc.. See also [here](http://superuser.com/questions/57317/editing-jpeg-exif-properties) and this comprehensive [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_metadata_editors).

Answer (score 11):

As of Gimp 2.9.4 (possibly 2.9.2) there is a built-in metadata editor/viewer. It is under the menu > Image > Image Metadata.

See http://libregraphicsworld.org/blog/entry/gimp-gets-advanced-exif-xmp-iptc-metadata-support

If you are on OSX and want a binary of this version (rather than compile from source), try [Partha's McGimp variants](http://www.partha.com/), the McGimp 2.9.5 64-bit Experimental, or McGimp 2.9.5 64-bit Color Corrected Experimental, an interesting project in its own right.

Comment: As of 2018-02-28, chocolatey provides GIMP 2.8.22 which has a very broken metadata editor.  It will not actually save the metadata entered. In some development versions, there may be a security feature that removes all MetaData, not just GPS, without prompting.

Comment: I couldn't find a way to edit using the metadata editor in GIMP 2.10.22. I ended up using https://products.groupdocs.app/metadata/total

Comment: The built-in medadata editor/viewer is very dissapointing as it only allows setting the date but not the time. Time is also very important to keep shots sorted correctly.