# How can I make Picasa see changes I make to photos using jhead?

Tags: picasa, exif

Last fall I forgot to set the time on my camera back an hour.  I used jhead to change the time in the EXIF data:

```
jhead -ta-1 IMG_1177.JPG
```

but Picasa didn't notice.  OS is Windows XP.

If I right-click the picture in Picasa and choose Properties, in the top section of the dialog it shows "Date: 3/6/2010 11:22:54 AM" but in the Property|Value section it shows "Camera Date | 2010:03:06 10:22:54".

I tried using "Refresh thumbnails" but that didn't help.  Picasa notices other changes, like if I edit the photo in the Gimp or change the filename, but for some reason it doesn't notice this change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/9492/how-do-i-batch-change-the-date-taken-information-in-exif-data/109810#109810):

> Picasa has this built-in. Tools => Adjust Date and Time....