# Set JPEG "date taken" attribute in EXIF info from filename

Tags: windows-7, exif

I have some files that are named like mmddyy_hhmm.jpg. I would like to automatically set their "Date Taken" attribute in the EXIF information based on their file names. Does anyone know of a way to do it using Windows?

Comment: being lazy I would probably use an exif edit along with a Mouse macro, copy paste ,do the action  , step one file, set the macro, to endlessly repeat, speed up the macro to get it done. I still like the crusty old GhostMouse2.0 http://superuser.com/questions/9492/how-do-i-batch-change-the-date-taken-information-in-exif-data?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

If you know your way around PowerShell, you could write a small script to loop through all your files and then use [jhead](http://www.sentex.net/~mwandel/jhead/) to update the date Exif field. Use

```
-ts<time>  Set the Exif internal time to <time>.  <time> is in the format
         yyyy:mm:dd-hh:mm:ss
```

So in PowerShell you would have to convert your date 'mmddyy_hhmm' to 'yyyy:mm:dd-hh:mm:ss'